# I am having trouble with a probability review problem I found online.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

The question is:

There are 3 ways a CEO can commit accounting fraud: (A) he can overstate
revenue by booking fake orders, (B) he can overstate profits by recording near-term expenses as longterm capital expenses, and (C) he can understate liabilities by making overly optimistic assumptions
about the growth prospects of the company’s pension funds. In the United States, 50% of CEOs commit fraud (A), 20% of CEOs commit fraud (B), 15% of CEOs commit both fraud (A) and fraud (B),
and all CEOs commit fraud (C).
The probability of getting caught if a CEO does (A) is 0.01, independent of whether or not he commits
other kinds of fraud. Similarly, the probability of getting caught if he does (B) is 0.05, and of getting
caught if he does (C) is 0.001.

a) What are the chances (rounded to 2 decimal places) that a CEO who perpetrates all 3 kinds of
fraud will get caught?

I feel like this is supposed to be a very simple question but I am struggling with it despite having an easy time with what I assumed were harder questions in the same place I found this one.

The problem I keep running into is that, any solution I can come up with requires I figure out the P(caught ∩ A ∩ B ∩ C). I have not been able to figure out P(caught ∩ A ∩ B ∩ C) so either I am looking in the wrong direction or there is a trick to solving for it that has not yet hit me.

Comment: Think of it backwards:  what is the probability that he gets away with each of the three crimes?  Note:  I expect you are intended to assume that the probability of conviction for one crime is independent of your conviction for any other.

Comment: 'all CEOs commit fraud [C]' - the questioner seems to hold a grudge!

Comment: The probability that the CEO gets away with committing A would just be 1-P(caught|A)=.99. Likewise, the probability the CEO gets away with B is .95, and the probability the CEO gets away with C is .999. I am not entirely sure how that helps me.

You are intended to assume the probability of conviction for one crime is independent of your conviction for any of the other crimes.

Comment: That independence assumption is not stated in the problem, though I agree one has to assume it get anywhere.  Anyway, as conviction is independent just multiply those three probabilities to discover the probability that gets away with no convictions.

Comment: I think I am misunderstanding your advice. My understanding is that you are saying:

P(caught | A)*P(caught | B)*P(caught | C)=P(not caught | A∩B∩C)

Comment: Of course not.  I am saying that the probability that he avoids conviction for all three crimes is the product of the  probabilities that he avoids conviction for each crime separately.  Once you know the probability that he avoids conviction, you can easily compute the probability that he is convicted (of at least one crime).

Comment: Wouldn't that suggest that P(caught ∩ A ∩ B ∩ C) = P(caught ∩ A)*P(caught ∩ B)*P(caught ∩ C), which can then be used with Bayes' Formula to get me P(caught | A ∩ B ∩ C), which would be the answer to the question?

Comment: I don't see what Bayes has to do with it.  The probability that he avoids conviction is $.99\times .95\times .999=0.9395595$ so the probability that he is convicted (of something) is $0.0604405$.

Comment: Oh! I kept focusing on the fact that the question is asking for the probability he is convicted given that he has committed all three crimes. I did not quite recognize that if he has committed all 3 types of fraud, I am really just looking for the probability that he gets convicted of any one crime. I keep viewing this as asking for the conditional probability P(convicted| A ∩ B ∩ C).

Just to verify. My understanding is correct, now, right?

Comment: Yes.  We are told that he committed all three crimes, so everything else is conditioned on that.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A, B, C$ denote committing crimes and $A_0,B_0,C_0$ denote caught with crimes.

a) What are the chances (rounded to 2 decimal places) that a CEO who perpetrates all 3 kinds of fraud will get caught?

In the language of my events, this question is asking for
$$
P(A_0\cup B_0\cup C_0 |ABC).
$$
The words "who perpetrates" is telling us the given and "caught" is a vague word for caught with one of the crimes.

By complement law, we have
$$
P(A_0\cup B_0\cup C_0 |ABC)=1-P(A_0^c B_0^c C_0^c|ABC).
$$
Now the trick is that regardless of what crimes were committed, it's always the case that the process of getting caught is independent. Hence, above equals
$$
1-P(A_0^c|ABC)P(B_0^c|ABC)P(C_0^c|ABC).
$$
It's also the case that knowing other crimes were committed is irrelevant so this simplifies to
$$
1-P(A_0^c|A)P(B_0^c|B)P(C_0^c|C).
$$